# Rsync NFS sync question

Tags: rsync, nfs

we have an NFS lun (EMC VNX5200) with 2 lun's of 15TB each, we are looking for a sync solution of these lun's to a remote site for DR, the date is backup blocks and contains million files with a large daily change, can someone recommend if Rsync can handle the job ?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: Does EMC have their own syncing product?